# Why Response.Redirect is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

here is my C# code in postback action

```
if (something-true)
   Response.Redirect("~/Admin/Home",true);
```

When I debug, I can see that executor come on this line but then also move to the next lines and finally go to the end and return View(). Why I am not redirecting to ~/Admin/Home???
After posting back its showing the main root url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using a [RedirectToAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470594.aspx) instead:

```
return RedirectToAction("Admin", "Home");
```

I'm assuming your controller is `HomeController` and your action method name is `Admin`.

Using RedirectToAction would fit the MVC paradigm much better.